# Web Audio API MediaElementSource node and SoundCloud not working with effects?

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud, web-audio-api

I am using a SoundCloud URL as `audio.src` . It is only playing the unprocessed version when i run it through the delay chain i have.
Here is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/nwaH3/

```
    var context = new webkitAudioContext();
    var audio = new Audio(); //creates a HTML5 Audio Element

    url = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/33925813/stream' + '?client_id=c625af85886c1a833e8fe3d740af753c';
    //wraps the soundcloud stream to an audio element.
    audio.src = url;

    var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    var input = context.createGainNode();
    var output = context.createGainNode();
    var fb = context.createGainNode();
    fb.gain.value = 0.4;

    var delay = context.createDelayNode();
    delay.delayTime.value = 0.5;


    //dry
    source.connect(input);
    input.connect(output);

    //wet
    input.connect(delay);
    delay.connect(fb);
    fb.connect(delay);
    delay.connect(output);

   source.mediaElement.play();
```

The chain works with Oscillator node.
What is the reason for it?

And is there any other way of processing a streaming sound from SoundCloud with Web Audio API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for the `canplaythrough` event on your audio element to fire before you can use it with `createMediaElementSource`.

So just add the event listener, and wait until the callback fires before you assign `source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);` and make all of your connections.

Here's an updated jsFiddle that'll do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/nwaH3/3/

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So this needs to render the file before playing through the audio context? And another question is there anyway that we can access the buffer before playing?

Comment: And is MediaStream Processing API going to aimed for this types of scenarios?

Comment: Well, it needs enough of the file that it can begin playback. Usually, that should happen pretty quickly. It doesn't mean the entire file has to be downloaded yet.

Not totally sure what you mean by "accessing the buffer before playing", but with `MediaElementSource` you can't access the entire buffer. You can do realtime processing with a `ScriptProcessorNode` though.

Is there a specific use case you have in mind that you're not sure how to implement?

Comment: i meant something like an `arraybuffer` with the audio data, so we could visualise the waveform and maybe select sections of the buffer to use in a sampler. as we have for `BufferSourceNode` for example.